# Error in running java program: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, exception, command-line, noclassdeffounderror

I have the following package structure where im trying to run a sample hibernate app

Source files: `/home/chander/workspace/HibernateApp/src/com/hib/TranslateSQL.java`

My current directory:

```
/home/chander/workspace/HibernateApp/src
```

Compile:
`$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac com/hib/*.java`  --- This ran successfully

Run:
`$JAVA_HOME/bin/java com/hib/TranslateSQL`  Giving the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TranslateSQL (wrong name: com/hib/TranslateSQL)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:315)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
Could not find the main class: TranslateSQL.  Program will exit.
```

I have my classpath and JAVA_HOME set. I dont seem to find what is wrong with my command.

Also tried the following command:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java com.hib.TranslateSQL
```

Got the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hib/TranslateSQL
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hib.TranslateSQL
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:315)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
Could not find the main class: com.hib.TranslateSQL.  Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by doing this:

```
cd  /home/chander/workspace/HibernateApp/src/com/hib/

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/chander/workspace/HibernateApp/src/

$JAVA_HOME/bin/java com.hib.TranslateSQL
```

Comment: That *shouldn't* have been necessary - the `-cp .` version in my answer should have been enough, unless the CLASSPATH *also* contained other things you needed, in which case the error message would have been different. You shouldn't need to be in the src/com/hib directory, either.

Answer (score 2):

You're specifying the classname incorrectly. Instead of this:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java com/hib/TranslateSQL
```

you should be running:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java com.hib.TranslateSQL
```

You should be specifying a *class name* which is within a package (`com.hib`), rather than a *file name* in a directory structure (`com/hib`.)

EDIT: If that's not working, your classpath may be set up incorrectly. You can specify it on the command line:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp . com.hib.TranslateSQL
```

Comment: Already tried that. Getting the following exception:           Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hib/TranslateSQL
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hib.TranslateSQL
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: @ChanderShivdasani: It's always worth saying what you've tried to avoid us repeating that... will edit.

Comment: @ChanderShivdasani: Check the top of my edited answer - please clarify whether or not you're actually in the `src` directory; at the moment your `javac` wouldn't find the source file you mentioned.

Comment: Oops, i made a mistake. I am infact in src directory. I will edit my post!

Comment: Tried giving the classpath through command line as well, still getting the same exception.

Comment: @ChanderShivdasani: Then something else is wrong. If you look in the com/hib directory, can you see `TranlateSQL.class`?

Comment: Yes, i can see TranslateSQL.class file